# Increase edittext height upto 5 lines as in whats app

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am implementing a chat application like WhatsApp and I would like to expand the `EditText` up to 5 lines as in WhatsApp. I am using the following code to achieve that but it is not working. The code I am using for `EditText` is:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/BottomLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_view_footer_height"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_0"
        android:background="#F8F7F7">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_0"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_0"
            android:background="#d3d3d3" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/add_icon"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_7"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_7"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/task_list_right_nav_arrow"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_7"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_7"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/footer_send" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageSend"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/add_icon"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/task_list_right_nav_arrow"
            android:textColorHint="#AEAEAE"
            android:hint="Message.."
            android:textColor="#333744"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:minLines="8"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Can anybody please give me a solution to achieve my requirement?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove `android:minLines="8"` and just use `android:maxLines="5"` .. This will work i guess .

Comment: @ADM yup you are right

Comment: @ADM It is not adjusting the height even after removing of minLines.

Comment: Well it should work .. MayBe this `EditText` have a Fix size parent .. Add your whole layout with question .

Comment: @ADM I have added my complete edittext code with its pareant. Yes you are right. After removing the fixed height of the parent it is working fine. But I want to that bottom layout section height as fixed and this editbox auto increase. Is there any way to satisfy both requirements. Please help...

Comment: `Like Whats app` ? does not satisfy the question.. I did not understand the requirement here . What happen if you  make the Relative Layout Height a `wrap_content`? [See this](https://github.com/Nimrodda/MaNishMa) or similar OSP.. This is the most i can do..

Comment: @ADM Thank you very much for the information. It is working fine now. Really you helped me a lot. Thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning `maxLines` as well as `minLines` attribute to the `EditText`. Change its code to this:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageSend"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/add_icon"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/task_list_right_nav_arrow"
            android:textColorHint="#AEAEAE"
            android:hint="Message.."
            android:textColor="#333744"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"/>
```

Comment: No it is not working after I copy and paste the above modified xml code.

Comment: try to remove android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"

Comment: @MuratVAROL I don't think so this would make a difference. But you can give it a try

Comment: interesting, I tried and worked. up to 5 lines it becomes multiple lines, and after 5 scrollbar appear

Comment: I am getting the scrollbar for third line only. And the edittext is not adjust the height

Answer (score 0):

Remove `minLines` atrribute and add `android:maxLines="5"`, you may also need to use `android:singleLine="false"`

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageSend"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/add_icon"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/task_list_right_nav_arrow"
        android:textColorHint="#AEAEAE"
        android:hint="Message.."
        android:textColor="#333744"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"/>
```

Comment: No it is not working after I copy and paste the above modified xml code.